# Не подключается к cassandra

Tags: java, база-данных, cassandra

При попытке подключения к cassandra cqlsh получаю вот такую ошибку

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})

При запуске cassandra вот такая ошибка

> ERROR 19:54:48 Fatal exception during initialization
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Found system keyspace files, but they couldn't be loaded!
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:922) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$9.execute(StartupChecks.java:325) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:112) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:187) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:581) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:710) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]

Comment: Судя по всему, повреждены файлы на диске. Это одна нода? Есть ли важные данные? 3.6 очень старая версия, к тому же с кучей багов. Лучше проапгрейдиться на 3.11.3

Comment: Да нет данных, только поставил. Да одна нода

Comment: Лучше тогда взять последний:  3.11.3

Comment: @AlexOtt, Помогло, спасибо)